how to diagnose unresponsive lxqt-session after boot in lubuntu noble
After release upgrade from jammy to noble I have a strange issue with my lxqt-session.
When I boot up the first session which started is unresponsive. My desktopstarter are not working. lxqt-panel is also not clickable. I have to switch to tty and kill this session with loginctl or restart my current displaymanger (lightdm).
egrep 'WW|EE' /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old 
[     7.748] Current Operating System: Linux Guilmon 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 30 12:02:04 UTC 2024 x86_64
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     7.751] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     7.751] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[     7.752] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[     8.908] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     8.931] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     8.974] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
[     9.251] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" is not used
[     9.251] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Option "PrimaryGPU" is not used
[     9.336] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER

What I try to pin it down. Switch from nvidia card to intel
lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 [8086:591b] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 630 [17aa:224d]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM206GLM [Quadro M2200 Mobile] [10de:1436] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Lenovo GM206GLM [Quadro M2200 Mobile] [17aa:224d]
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Trying different display-manager like gdm3 sddm.
Replace openbox with kwin-x11.
In my .xsession-errors I see
Emergency] X11 error: type: 0, serial: 307, error_code: 10 'BadAccess (attempt to
access private resource denied)

Little update: this error I could eliminate. (was related to xbindkeys_autostart)
In journal
journalctl -b -1 | grep -i X11
Okt 05 11:42:24 Guilmon kernel: pci 0000:00:14.2: [8086:a131] type 00 class 0x118000 conventional PCI endpoint
Okt 05 11:42:24 Guilmon kernel: pci 0000:00:15.0: [8086:a160] type 00 class 0x118000 conventional PCI endpoint
Okt 05 11:48:34 Guilmon kglobalaccel5[2772]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Okt 05 11:48:34 Guilmon kglobalaccel5[2772]: The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
Okt 05 11:48:34 Guilmon pulseaudio[2685]: X11 I/O error handler called
Okt 05 11:48:34 Guilmon pulseaudio[2685]: X11 I/O error exit handler called, preparing to tear down X11 modules
Okt 05 12:09:26 Guilmon sudo[5805]:     alex : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/alex ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-map.conf backup/
Okt 05 12:10:51 Guilmon kglobalaccel5[3476]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?
Okt 05 12:10:51 Guilmon kglobalaccel5[3476]: The X11 connection broke: I/O error (code 1)
Okt 05 12:10:51 Guilmon pulseaudio[2685]: X11 I/O error handler called
Okt 05 12:10:51 Guilmon pulseaudio[2685]: X11 I/O error exit handler called, preparing to tear down X11 modules
Okt 05 12:10:51 Guilmon org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.lxqt[4186]: The X11 connection broke (error 1). Did the X11 server die?

I removed every old xorg.conf.d created by me. Removed own udev-rules too (related to mouse or touchpad) and everything in my autostart folder in $HOME created by my own.
Started with latest GA-kernel from jammy ( I mark this always as manual before I upgrade)
And now I'm running out of idea where to look.
The is a dualboot with debian bookworm. Starting grub is from debian
No docker kvm or something like that involved. (and no snap)
